# How to make a screen-reader go through a <span> without any stopping

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, narrator

I have this span element:

```
<span>Select the <strong>START</strong> <span class="icon-start></span> button.</span>
```

That is just a line that says "Select the START button" with a small icon after the word START.

Currently, Microsoft Narrator (in scan mode) reads "select the start" and then pauses at the icon and waits for the user to tell it to continue.  I'm trying to make the Narrator read the entire line with zero interruptions or need for the user to tell it to continue.

So far here's what I've tried:

- Add `aria-hidden="true"`, `tabindex="-1"`, and `role="presentation` to the icon's `<span>`
- Wrapped the span in a `<div>` and gave it `aria-hidden="true"`, `tabindex="-1"`, and `role="presentation`
- Added a `role="heading"` to the outer span -which works to make the Narrator reading everything uninterrupted, but he announces "Heading level 1" at first.  If there's a way to prevent him from saying "heading" then that could work too.

Is there a role or aria attribute that tells the screen-reader to continue reading with no stopping?

Comment: Do you have a sample URL where I can test this? Is this with Edge and Windows 10 Creators Update? Does it stop in other places where you use an icon? Did you try it with just `aria-hidden="true"` on the `<span>` (note that the `tabindex="-1"` should have no effect, and `role="presentation"` is mostly redundant)? Does it behave this way in other screen readers (your question title is less specific about the SR)?

Comment: Here's the URL: `https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14238/windows-10-troubleshoot-blue-screen-errors` if you scroll down to 'When did you get the error?' then click 'While upgrading to windows 10' > 'Remove Software'.  You should see the panel with all of the text mixed with icons.  I am testing using Edge and the typical Microsoft Narrator as my screen reader.

Comment: When I expand "Remove Software", it announces that control has expanded something, which is what I expect. In this pattern, the expanded area should immediately follow the control, which is does. It should not be a live region, since this is a disclosure widget. With Caps-Lock + Space you can enter browse mode and use the arrow keys to wade into the content. IOW, I think this example works fine.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified.  With Caps-Lock + Space on, below "remove software" on the second `<p>` there is a sentence with icons inside of it.  While still in scan mode, I am trying to make it so a sentence like this is read all the way through.  Currently, the narrator stops at every icon.  Then says "group" after the user presses an arrow button to proceed.

Comment: Ah. Gotcha. No, I am not aware of any way to change that. I feel that is a quirk (not quite a bug) in Narrator though. As such, there is likely no programmatic way to do what you want without impacting other screen readers (that also have a greater market share). Ping the MS Accessibility team?

Comment: Pinged MS the quickest way I know how: https://twitter.com/aardrian/status/869941374736531457

Comment: Does narrator stop on every `<span>`? Or only one some with `class="icon…`? The latter would make sense to me, since often icons serve as buttons (in bad code). Changing the class name might solve it then.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the screen reader is failing to parse your icon span — that span should have `aria-hidden=“true”`.

As a note, avoid making text items headings unless they are really meant to be headings. As a best practice, an accessible webpage should only have one `<h1>`  element that essentially serves as a page title. And other headings below that single `<h1>` should be an `<h2>` and any headings below those should be `<h3>` etc. So, I'd advise you to be thoughtful about the heading level you choose if you were to go that route.

Comment: Decent advice, @garret, but be careful when you state that things are in WCAG.  WCAG 1.3.1 is generally the success criteria used for bad headings, but 1.3.1 does not say you must only have one h1 or that an h2 must follow an h1.  It's certainly good advice, but if you don't do that, it doesn't necessarily fail WCAG.  And regarding an `aria-label` on a `<span>`, the label will generally be ignored because a `<span>` is a non-semantic element.  See the third last bullet point on https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support.

Comment: Noted! I will update my comment accordingly. Thank you, @slugolicious!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like this:

```html
<span aria-label="Select the START button">
  <span aria-hidden="true">
    Select the <strong>START</strong> <span class="icon-start"></span> button.
  </span>
</span>
```

This will announce the correct text and hide the presentation content from screen readers.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like Narrator has a similar behavior as VoiceOver on iOS devices.  If you have an element that contains nested elements, VoiceOver often stops at each element even though you want to treat it as one element.  You can typically work around this for iOS using an **undocumented** `role="text"`.  I don't know if it will work for Narrator too.

You'd have something like this:

```
<span role="text">Select the <strong>START</strong> <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-start></span> button.</span>
```

Note that I also included `aria-hidden` on the icon, which @garret wisely recommended, so that it won't be read.  You might not need `aria-hidden` when using `role="text"` but since that role is **undocumented** and technically **not supported**, you'd have to test it.